# Is there any solution to remove messages from redis stream 1 by 1 from backend & frontend while maxmemory reached

Tags: java, redis

We are using redis stream in our application. we have 2 docker service for the same. Service1(Java) publishing data to stream & Service2(C++) consuming that data & after consuming we are deleting that entry using xdel from stream.

Now requirement is that if Service2 gets down then data should be stored in stream until the allowed maxmemory size exhausted (we will set maxmemory for that around 50-100MB)
So if that memory limit reaches then it should delete old data 1 by 1.

But current behavior with config(maxmemory:50mb, maxmemory-policy:allkeys-lru) is that it is not deleting 1 by 1. it deletes whole data from stream. Example:-

```
(integer) 93
127.0.0.1:6379> xlen MyStream
(integer) 94
127.0.0.1:6379> xlen MyStream
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379> xlen MyStream
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> xlen MyStream
(integer) 2
```

Is there any solution/configuration for this requirement

Comment: It seems like you have an eviction policy set so the key is being evicted, is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

According to Redis documentation on [eviction policies](https://docs.redislabs.com/latest/rs/administering/database-operations/eviction-policy/) there is no option to specify eviction per entry - they apply on keys.

There is however another option add entries into a stream with capped memory usage:

[Capped Streams](https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro)

By specifying a value for `MAXLEN` when calling [`XADD`](https://redis.io/commands/xadd), you can cap the stream to a fixed length. You will have to calculate this maximum length based on your entries so it will keep memory usage to 50-100MB.